# How do I call ipython modules in a short-hand way?

Tags: numpy, plot, ipython

I'm learning python, and using notebooks;
My tutorial is telling my to use

```
randn(5)
```

but this only works for me when I use the fully qualified method; ie:

```
np.random.randn(5)
```

I imported numpy as np. Is there something else I need to do to make this work? I also wanted shorthand notation when calling plot() as well.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the fully qualified name - in fact I'd argue that it is better - because the source of the function is clear.  You could use `randn = np.random.randn` to save some typing, but only do so when the context is clear.

Comment: Loading `ipython --pylab` loads `numpy` with the `*` syntax; so you can skip the `np.`.  But I've disabled that feature, because import with * creates too much ambiguity.  It's good to know that `randn` comes from `np` and `plot` comes from `plt` (or is it something else?).

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial likely assume that `%pylab` was called, or IPython was started with `--pylab`. The pylab magic does:

```
from pylab import *
```

which includes

```
from numpy import *
```

and other things, hiding where functions come from. The tutorial should probably not assume that you have done this, but if it does, it should be very clear about that fact, and mention what has happened and where these functions are coming from.

These days, it is typically considered prudent in teaching materials to make imports like this explicit, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randn(x)
```

or

```
from numpy.random import randn
randn(x)
```

especially in a notebook, where saving a few characters of typing is much less precious than in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `%pylab inline` it works! Thanks

Comment: I use the plain `ipython` shell (and sometimes `qtconsole`), but rarely the notebook.